# How to get tty from kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am new to kernel module programming and got some problem while compiling some old kernel code.

The code is trying to get `tty` for the current task using `current->tty`, but when I compile, I get following an error

```
error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘tty’
  my_tty = current->tty;
```

I checked the linux source code , `tty` is not there any more.

The 'current' is of task_struct,but `tty` not in `struct task_struct` any more. 
How can I access them in version `3.13.0-24`?

Comment: Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719713/how-can-i-write-to-tty-from-a-kernel-module

Following this LXR the method should be there in 3.13 as well: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.13;i=get_current_tty